# Powershell output

Tags: powershell

I'm having a little issue with controlling output in ps.  Here's the line of code in question;

```
$result|sort-object cn  | format-table -wrap -autosize
```

If I append

```
| out-file $logfile
```

the last column of my output is truncated.  Now I know that if I changed the width of my console session and run the script again, my output is fine, but there must be a better way of doing this?  I also attempted to use add-content but I think I must be missing something as the expression isn't being evalulated correctly and I just get a series of references to system-object in my logfile.

Comment: You might try serverfault.com

Comment: I think it belongs here, since it's obviously an algorithm gone wrong instead of a server management problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the -width parameter for the out-file cmdlet. You might try out-file -width 500 so nothing gets truncated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've determined so far is to use Out-String with a -Width longer than you expect the entire line to be:

```
$result | Format-Table -Autosize | Out-String -Width 4096
```

The only problem with the above is that it will pad the entire line with spaces.  In order to get around that, add the -Stream switch and .Trim() each line:

```
$result | Format-Table -Autosize | Out-String -Width 4096 -Stream | %{ $_.Trim() }
```

This is also nice for piping the results to the clipboard with clip.exe (if I don't have the PSCX module installed with the Out-Clipboard command):

```
$result | Format-Table -Autosize | Out-String -Width 4096 -Stream | %{ $_.Trim() } | clip.exe
```